# how to make custom-data-attribute value numeric with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, custom-data-attribute

Hi I am reading two numbers from html data-tags stored in a div. When I try to add the numbers together they are appended as strings. Is there anyways to include numbers in a data attribute and access them as numbers or convert them back into non - string numbers with javascript thanks.

Example

```
<div data-Lon1="1.3" data-Lat1="-1.2"></div>

<script>
   lon1 = $('#zoom1').attr('data-lon1');
   lat1 = $('#zoom1').attr('data-lat1');
   console.log(lat1+lon1);

   //returns '1.3-1.2' (I want .1 in this example)
</script>
```

Comment: An easier way to access data attributes you can use is this btw: $("zoom1").data("lon1");

Comment: for some reason trying to access the data with the data method returns undefined. Does this only work if you store the data with the data method as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `parseFloat()`:

```
var lon1 = parseFloat($('#zoom1').attr('data-lon1'));
   lat1 = parseFloat$('#zoom1').attr('data-lat1'));
console.log(lat1+lon1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/G4zqy/).

References:

- [`number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: this works great, thanks... Do you know if this faster than using the data() method?

Comment: @codelove It should be faster since jQuery doesn't have to interpret what type of data it is, though I would still prefer the `.data` method.

Comment: I defer to Kevin B in this, but I have no objective evidence to support that assumption (other than simple common sense, based on work-avoidance).

Comment: Yes, testing that micro-optimization would be a waste of time unless you are dealing with a (very)large number of elements, and you would have to consider cross-browser differences since some browsers provide an api for accessing these values directly which may be faster than the .attr approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method which will take care of properly parsing the value to the underlying type:

```
var lon1 = $('#zoom1').data('lon1');
var lat1 = $('#zoom1').data('lat1');
console.log(lat1 + lon1);
```

You will notice that when using the `.data()` method you are no longer passing as argument the full attribute name, but only the suffix - `lon1` and `lat1` instead of `data-lon1` and `data-lat1`.

And here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E7Av7/

Oh, and don't forget to give a correct id to your div so that your data selector returns something as you seem to have forgotten to do this in the code snippet posted in your question:

```
<div data-Lon1="1.3" data-Lat1="-1.2" id="zoom1"></div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript function called `parseFloat`. Use `parseFloat($("#zoom1").attr("data-lon1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data()` which attempts to parse the value.

```
var lon1 = $('div').data('lon1');
var lat1 = $('div').data('lat1');
console.log(lat1+lon1);
```

If you want the result to be `0.1` from that though, you must do something like:

```
console.log( Math.round( ( lat1+lon1 ) * 100000000000 ) / 100000000000 );
```

Otherwise you will get `0.10000000000000009` instead of `0.1`

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

http://jsfiddle.net/E7Av7/1/